# $(...).swMegamenu is not a function

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs

I'm using Smartwave Porto theme for my Magento 2 website, when I load my website for the first time in browser console it shows no error at all, but every time I refresh the browser page by pressing `F5` or `CTRL+SHIFT+R`, it will show an error like this in browser console and my page not load properly because of this:

[image: error]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).swMegamenu is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).stellar is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function
```

*If you suffer the same, do this:*

create a requirejs-config.js in the root of the child theme

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child and put in the following:
```

```
 var config = {
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'Smartwave_Megamenu/js/sw_megamenu':
            {
                deps: ['jquery']
            }, 
        'owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min':
            {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
        'js/jquery.stellar.min': 
            {
            deps: ['jquery']
            },
        'js/jquery.parallax.min':
            {
            deps: ['jquery']
            }
    }
};
```

*And change the entries:*

```
    <script src="jquery.js" />
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
    <script src="fancybox/js/jquery.fancybox.js" />
```

*To:*

```
    <remove src="jquery.js" />
    <remove src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
    <remove src="fancybox/js/jquery.fancybox.js" />
```

*Within file:*

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

No more need for merging javascripts, no more javascript errors!
I have no need for the fancybox, turned it off, but if you do require it, I guess it should be included in the requirejs as well.

Comment: thanks it's working, but what cause this problem to be exact?

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to hear that it helped you. The problem was that menu JavaScript was being loaded before jQuery. So we defined dependency of that menu JS.

Comment: Hello @KishanPatadia I have the same issue  with porto theme. I used this code which is working fine. But after this solution product page is showing error ( zoom is not a function )

Comment: @KishanPatadia there's a problem, when i go to product page i got an error saying: `$(...).zoom is not a function`

Comment: `$(...).zoom is not a function` is an issue with another call to a js library that hasn't been added to the require js file. I don't have that library call on the site i'm working on, so i can't give a code solution to your case, but looking at @KishanPatadia example, you should be able to find the library for zoom and add it to the require js file. In my case, i had to add `fancybox` to mine with `'fancybox/js/jquery.fancybox': { deps: ['jquery'] }` and that cleaned up all my issues.

Comment: Not working for me, Getting new js error "Fancybox library is not loaded".